# How do I make a question in Bash that can read any question given?

Tags: bash

I'm making a small dungeon dwelling text game. How can I make a custom response question? I am stuck on just asking for a name. I have:

```
#!/bin/bash/env bash

clear  
echo "Welcome, Traveler, ..."|pv -qL 10  
clear  
echo "What is your name $NAME?" |pv -qL 10  
read $NAME  
echo "I see.. $NAME?" |pv -qL 10
```

I don't know how to get it to register the name for later use.

Comment: Drop the `$`; the argument to `read` is the name of the variable you want to set.

Comment: That said, since `NAME` wasn't set and `$NAME` was unquoted, `read $NAME` is equivalent to `read` alone, in which case the variable `REPLY` is set; `echo "I see.. $REPLY?"` would do what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the dollar sign when calling `read`. It needs the name of the variable to assign to (`NAME`) rather than its value (`$NAME`).

```
read NAME
```